# AngularJS validation input different than zero

Tags: html, angularjs, validation, input

starting that I'm realy new in progrraming especialy Angular. I want to validate input not to allow number 0 . Here is my code:

```
<form ng-app="linearEquation" ng-controller="calcCtrl" 
              name="calculator" ng-init="notValid=true" novalidate>
        <div>
            <h3 class="field">Kalkulator oblicza wartość równania 
                <var>ax = b</var>.</h3>
            <div class="field">
                <p>
                    Podaj wartość a:<br/>
                    <input type="number" name="fieldA" ng-model="a" required integer />
                    <span class="error" ng-show="calculator.fieldA.$invalid"/>
                    <span  ng-show="calculator.fieldA.$error.number">
                    Proszę podać liczbę</span><br/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Podaj wartość b:<br/>
                    <input type="number" name="fieldB" ng-model="b" required integer />
                    <span class="error" ng-show="calculator.fieldB.$invalid"/>
                    <span  ng-show="calculator.fieldB.$error.number">
                    Proszę podać liczbę</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit"   
                                ng-disabled="
                                    calculator.fieldA.$dirty &&
                                    calculator.fieldA.$invalid ||
                                    calculator.fieldB.$dirty &&  
                                    calculator.fieldB.$invalid" 
                                 ng-click="count()">
                        Oblicz
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <p class="field" id="result">x = {{c.toFixed(2)}}</p>
        </div>
```

How should I validate it. Also the button doesn't seem to be disabled on load of the page. How to manage this?

Comment: It's not disabled because it can only be disabled if at least one field is dirty and invalid. The condition should be `ng-disabled="calculator.$invalid"`.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the both `$dirty` if you want the button to disabled on start. And you better use `ng-pattern` directive to validate numbers 1-9 and omit "0". Your `input` should look like something like that:

```
<input type="number" name="fieldA" ng-model="a" required ng-pattern="/[1-9]/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I understan two case here 
first that in field 0 should not be allowed at all for example 0 is invalid and 10 is also invalid 550 is also invalid
In that case use

```
<input type="number" name="fieldA" ng-model="a" required ng-pattern="/[1-9]*/" />
```

second case zero zero could be part of number but value 0 should not be allowed for example 0 is invalid but 01 is valid, 501, is valid and 0000 is invalid in that case

```
<input type="number" name="fieldA" ng-model="a" required ng-pattern="/([1-9][0-9]*||[0]*[1-9]+[0-9]*)/" />
```

according to regular expression if it starts with 1-9 it can have any number after that, if it starts with 0 it should have atleast one non zero value followed by it